# Traversing DOM in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, imacros

I wrote this in JQuery,

```
for (var i = 1; i < 18; i++) {
    $(".foo table > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + i + ") > .goo:nth-child(2) > a").click();
}
```

However, I'm running this in IMacros, and sadly it doesn't support JQuery. After some hours fiddling with JS, I can't really get it to work.

Can someone help me writing this piece in plain javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: Even if you could use jQuery, that would not be the way to do it. If you've tried to convert this, show what you've tried so that we can help you understand where you went wrong.

Comment: Oh my God! They downvote a so good question... Use `document.querySelector('...')`

Comment: @Bellash: It received one downvote from someone, and 3 upvotes. What are you complaining about? It isn't a good question. It's basically a "convert the jQuery code for me" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 1; i < 18; i++) {
    document.querySelector(".foo table > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + i + ") > .goo:nth-child(2) > a").click();
}
```